# helgrind says "Bug in libpthread"

Tags: pthreads, conditional-statements, valgrind

I am running helgrind to check for data races in my program. Helgrind reports 222 errors, all of them are:

```
Thread #21: Bug in libpthread: pthread_cond_wait succeeded without prior pthread_cond_post
```

I could not find anything about this error message on google. Within the valgrind source code, this seems to originate here:

```
if (!timeout && !libhb_so_everSent(cvi->so)) {
      /* Hmm.  How can a wait on 'cond' succeed if nobody signalled
         it?  If this happened it would surely be a bug in the threads
         library.  Or one of those fabled "spurious wakeups". */
      HG_(record_error_Misc)( thr, "Bug in libpthread: pthread_cond_wait "
                                   "succeeded"
                                   " without prior pthread_cond_post");
}
```

However, I can not believe that I got 222 spurious wake-ups in about a second.

What could be the cause of this?

There are two condition variables, both in shared memory. The error always seems to happen with one of them, not with the other.

Comment: Can you provide a small compilable program producing the problem ?

Comment: What versions of Valgrind and pthread on what OS?